# Cannot connect to local instance of SQL Server database using Entity Framework Code First - error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, iis, code-first

I have an MVC web application using EF 5.0 (Code first) that connects to a local database (on the same server) using this connection string:

```
"Data Source={server}\{instance};Database={database};user id=sa;password={password}"
```

The database is dropped and re-created when the DbContext is first initialised. After that it throws the following exception:

> System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException: An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct. ---> System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

I've hosted another application on the same server, using exactly the same connection string to access the database using a SqlConnection object in old-school ADO.Net fashion which connects fine.

I've checked for similar posts and all suggest a number of things which I have tried but have not solved the problem:

- Add TCP/IP aliases for server instances
- Check firewall allows inbound connectivity via TCP:1433 and UDP:1434 ports
- Check that SQL Server Browser is running on the server
- Check that the connection string is valid and that the specified user has access to the SQL Server instance

Just to add a odd twist to the whole thing: I can connect to the same database on the same server from my workstation running IIS Express but as soon as it's hosted on the server I get the above problem.